# Transversally intersecting divisors $C$ and $D$ in a Hartshorne's AG lemma

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors

Question about proof of lemma V.1.3 in Robin Hartshorne's
Algebraic Geometry on page 358.
Let $X$ be surface. That's for us a nonsingular projective
surface over an algebraically closed field $k$ and for any divisor
$D \subset X$ (that's a curve) we call
$\mathcal{L}(D)$ the related invertible sheaf of $D$ on $X$.

> Lemma 1.3. Let $C$ be an irreducible nonsingular curve on $X$, and
> let $D$ be any curve meeting $C$ transversally. Then
> $$\#(C \cap D) = 
> \operatorname{deg}_C(\mathcal{L}(D) \otimes_{O_X} \mathcal{O}_C)$$.

> PROOF. Here, of course, $\mathcal{L}(D)$ is the invertible sheaf on
> $X$ corresponding to curve $D$
> ($II, §7$), and $\operatorname{deg}_C$ denotes the degree of the
> invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C$
> on $C$ ($IV, §1$). We use the fact $(II, 6.18)$ that $\mathcal{L}(-D)$
> is the ideal sheaf of $D$ on $X$.
> Therefore, tensoring

$$ 0 \to \mathcal{L}(-D) \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_D \to 0 $$

> with $\mathcal{O}_C$, we have an exact sequence

$$ 0 \to \mathcal{L}(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C \to \mathcal{O}_C 
\to \mathcal{O}_{C \cap D} $$

> where now $C \cap D$ denotes the scheme-theoretic intersection.
> Thus $\mathcal{L}(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C$
> is the invertible sheaf on $C$ corresponding to the divisor $C \cap D$.

This proof has a part I not understand. Why if we tensor the injection
$0 \to \mathcal{L}(-D) \to \mathcal{O}_X$ on the left with $\mathcal{O}_C$
the induced $\mathcal{L}(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C$ is still injective?

The only assumption on $C$ and $D$ we use is that are transversally.
This means (page 357) that for every point $P \in C \cap D$
the local equations $f,g \in \mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ of $C,D$ at $P$ generate
the maximal $\mathfrak{m}_P$ of $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$. This implies
also that $C$ and $D$ are each nonsingular
at $P$, because $f$ will generate the maximal ideal of $P$ in
$\mathcal{O}_{D,P} = \mathcal{O}_{X,P}/(g)$
and vice versa.

Why this assumption is sufficient to get the injectivity? Let's discuss
it locally, set $A:= \mathcal{O}_{X,P}$, $f, g \in A$ are local equations
of $C$ and $D$ at $P$ and we tensor the canonical injection

$$ 0 \to g \cdot A \to A $$

with $A/(f)$ and obtain

$$g \cdot A \otimes_A A/(f) \to A/(f) $$

and I want to check that it's injective. Note that that's the canonical
map given by $g \cdot a \otimes b \mapsto g \cdot a \cdot b$
where $a \in A$ and $b \in A/(f)$. Assume the map is not injetive,
then there exist $a \in A$ and $b \in A \backslash (f)$ with
$g \cdot ab \in (f)$. Transversallity says that $g \notin (f) $ but
the regular local ring $A= \mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ is not assumed
to be unique factorization domain, therefore it is in general
not possible to conclude that $b \in (f)$, which would contradict to assumption. This not helps to prove injectivity of the map $g \cdot A \otimes_A A/(f) \to A/(f)$.
Any other idea to give a formally correct argument?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ generate the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X, P}$, then $f$ generates the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X, P}/g = \mathcal{O}_{D, P}$. In particular, $f$ is a nonzerodivisor in $\mathcal{O}_{D, P}$, which gives the injectivity of the map.

Comment: Why the fact that $f$ generates the maximal ideal of 
$\mathcal{O}_{X, P}/g = \mathcal{O}_{D, P}$ implies that
$f$ is not a zerodivisor in this local ring? Clearly, if we eg know
that the curve $D$ is regular in $P$, then $\mathcal{O}_{D, P}$ is 
dvr and we are done, but $D$ is not assumed to be non singular. Which 
property of $\mathcal{O}_{D, P}$ do you essentially exploit here to conclude 
that the generator of it's maximal ideal cannot be a zerodivisor?

Comment: The ring $\mathcal{O}_{D, P}$ is one-dimensional ($D$ is a curve) and the maximal ideal is generated by one element. It is therefore regular, in particular a domain.

Comment: i see it now, thank you. So this tensoring-by-structure-sheaf-of-the-
divisor-trick keeping the involved sequence exact works only for
surfaces and curves (+additional assumpion how they intersect)
but hardly fails in higher dimensions without any hope to 'repair' it
also if we require
that the divisors intersect way 'nice'?